# How to color the output of awk depending on a condition

Tags: shell, awk

I have an input file test.txt containing the fallowing:

```
 a 1 34
 f 2 1
 t 3 16
 g 4 11
 j 5 16
```

I use awk to print only string 2 and 3:

```
awk '{print $2 " " $3}' test.txt
```

Is there a way to color only the second string of my output depending on a condition, if the value is higher than 15 then print in orange, if the value is higher than 20, print in red. It will give the same but colored:

```
1 34(red)
2 1
3 16(orange)
4 11
5 16(orange)
```

The input could contain many more lines in a different order.

Comment: Are you asking about how to colorize an output string or how to do that based on a conditional or both?

Comment: I'm asking for both, if value is higher than 15 then print in orange, if higher than 20 then print in red, below 15 then just print normally.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This awk command should do what you want:

```
awk -v red="$(tput setaf 1)" -v yellow="$(tput setaf 3)" -v reset="$(tput sgr0)" '{printf "%s"OFS"%s%s%s\n", $1, ($3>20)?red:($3>15?yellow:""), $3, reset}'
```

The key bits here are

- the use of `tput` to get the correct representation of setting the color for the current terminal (as opposed to hard-coding a specific escape sequence)
- the use of `-v` to set the values of the variables the awk command uses to construct its output

The above script is tersely written but could be written less tersely like this:

```
{
    printf "%s"OFS, $1
    if ($3 > 20) {
        printf "%s", red
    } else if ($3 > 15) {
        printf "%s", yellow
    }
    printf "%s%s\n", $3, reset
}
```

Edit: Ed Morton correctly points out that the awk programs above could be simplified by using a `color` variable and separating the color choice from the printing. Like this:

```
awk -v red="$(tput setaf 1)" -v yellow="$(tput setaf 3)" -v reset="$(tput sgr0)" \
'{
    if ($3>20) color=red; else if ($3>15) color=yellow; else color=""
    printf "%s %s%s%s\n", $1, color, $3, reset
}'
```

Comment: +1 FWIW I'd have found `if ($3>20) color=red; else if ($3>15) color=yellow; else color=""; printf "%s %s%s%s\n", $1, color, $3, reset` clearer...

Comment: @EdMorton Indeed. I'm going to blame "strict translation" blindness for that one.

Comment: Yes it does the job, it is quite long but I like the use of tput, I used it and its perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```
awk '{printf "%s ", $2}
     $3 > 15 {printf "\033[33m"}
     $3 > 20 {printf "\033[31m"}
     {printf "%s\033[0m\n", $3}' test.txt
```

Unfortunately, I don't know the orange ansi escape code...

Another approach:

```
awk -v color1="\033[33m" -v color2="\033[31m" -v reset="\033[0m" '
     $3 > 15 && $3 <= 20 {$3=color1 $3 reset}
     $3 > 20 {$3=color2 $3 reset}
     {print $2, $3}' test.txt
```

Comment: I like yours because it is very simple and easy to add after a pipe, thanks for the command.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{if($2>15 && $2<=20){$2="\033[1;33m" $2 "\033[0m"};if($2>20){$2="\033[1;31m" $2 "\033[0m"};print}' file
```

breakdown

```
($2>15 && $2<=20){$2="\033[1;33m" $2 "\033[0m"}  # if field 2>15 and =<20, then add colour code to field 2.

if($2>20){$2="\033[1;31m" $2 "\033[0m"} ## if field 2>20, then add colour code to field 2.

print #print line afterwards
```

Comment: This one is good too, it is funny how a different way leads to the same result.