# Colorize one of the output fields if there is a condition in Linux Terminal

Tags: linux, shell

I want to display that number when I execute "df -h" command, if the number in the Use% column is greater than 80%.

```
/dev/sda4        20G  9.0G  9.7G  49% /
tmpfs           252G  976M  251G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda2       488M   82M  381M  18% /boot
/dev/sda6       9.8G   24M  9.2G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda3        99G   28G   66G  81% /u01
/dev/sda7       9.8G  2.4G  6.9G  26% /var
```

Comment: You have to write a program or script which reads the output from "df" and evaluate the value and output it with the color settings for the terminal. But it is quite to broad to tell you how to write the prog or script here! How to set color on terminal: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: Use `df -h | awk ...` and then look at this answer for colouring based on condition... https://stackoverflow.com/a/28573866/2836621 and consider adding the `awk` tag.

Comment: Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.